# SQL In Clause with 20000 values

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sql-in

I have a xls with 20000 IDs

I need to extract the rows of a table that have these IDs in Col1

Is there a clever way to do this in Oracle SQL ?

I only have a read access to this db.

I thought to slice the 20000 IDs, in order to put the first 1000 in a variable p_list1 , the next 1000 in a variable p_list2, ect and use a IN clause and union to get the whole result

But I'm not used to use paramters in my query.

Could you please review it ?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
DECLARE
             p_list1 VARCHAR2(10) := '''id1''','''id2''','''id3''',..ect 
BEGIN
execute immediate 'select * from table1 where Col1 in ('|| p_list ||')' ;
END;
```

Comment: `But I'm not used to use paramters in my query` You should urgently fix that vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a temporary table, you can proceed in this way:

1. Create temporary table
2. Re-write your query with an EXISTS clause, as follow:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table1 
 WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from temp_table tt WHERE tt.id = table1.Col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One handy workaround is to use a list of tuples instead of a list of values. For whatever reason, Oracle allows more than 2000 *tuples* in a `in` condition, while it disallows more than 2000 values.

So:

```
declare
    p_list clob := '(1, ''id1''), (1, ''id2''), (1, ''id3'')';
begin
    execute immediate 'select * from table1 where (1, col1) in ('|| p_list ||')' ;
end;
/
```

Note that I changed the `p_list` parameter to a CLOB; if it is going to contain more than 2000 values, that's probably more than 4000 bytes. I also fixed the single quotes sequence.

This stills leaves you with an injection problem, if your paramaters come from outside your code: in that case, you really want to use a prepared statement rather than `execute immediate` (the same logic can be used, though).